# WPF C# PreviewDrop/Drop event not fired ( With dragadorner)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drag-and-drop, adorner

I assume that previewdrop/drop events fired when it detect a drag target with an element as a drop target . In this case , my drop target is a textbox and my drag target is a label. Both of them are dynamically created from DB . I am using DragAdorner to clone the element that i am dragging , before implementing the DragAdorner , my DnD works well but after i use the dragadorner , it won't work . And i notice my previewdrop event is not firing when i try to debug .

Here are my codes :

```
 tbox.Drop += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDrop); // text box , Drop Target
 tbox.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(tbox_DragOver);

Label lbl = new Label();  // Label , Drag Target 
             lbl.Content = s;
             lbl.Width = Double.NaN;
             lbl.Height = 40;
             lbl.FontSize = 19;
             lbl.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(lbl_MouseDown);
             lbl.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(lbl_MouseMove);
            lbl.PreviewGiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(lbl_GiveFeedback);


     private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
      //  Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;

    }

    private void lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {

          //  Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;

            var source = sender as UIElement;
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            Point current = e.GetPosition(this);
            Vector diff = startPoint - current;

            if (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {

                adorner = new DragAdorner(lbl, e.GetPosition(lbl));
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(lbl).Add(adorner);

                var dragData = new DataObject(this);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(source, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(lbl).Remove(adorner);

            }
            startPoint = current;
        }
    }

    private void lbl_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (adorner != null)
        {
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            var pos = lbl.PointFromScreen(GetMousePosition());
            adorner.UpdatePosition(pos);
            e.Handled = true;

        }
    }



private void tbox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

            (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; // Empty the textbox from previous answer.
            (sender as TextBox).Background = Brushes.White;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            e.Handled = true;

        }

        private void tbox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;

        }
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    public static Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }

    private Point startPoint;
    private DragAdorner adorner;
```

And the adorner class file :

```
 public class DragAdorner : Adorner {

public DragAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, Point offset)

    : base(adornedElement) {

    this.offset = offset;

    vbrush = new VisualBrush(AdornedElement);
    //vbrush.Opacity = .7;

}



public void UpdatePosition(Point location) {

    this.location = location;

    this.InvalidateVisual();

}



protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {

    var p = location;

    p.Offset(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

    dc.DrawRectangle(vbrush, null, new Rect(p, this.RenderSize));

}



private Brush vbrush;

private Point location;

private Point offset;
```

}

I seen http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf ( page 103 ) but its way too complicated for me as i am a newbie .

It is because of my GiveFeedBack event that is in conflict with other events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `DragAdorner` is always under your cursor, it will be the object receiving the drop. If you set `IsHitTestVisible = false;` in the constructor for the `Adorner`, it should fix this.

Even though you haven't set `AllowDrop` on the `Adorner`, since it is under the cursor, it will intercept the drop attempt. But since it doesn't accept drop, it will just cancel it.

**Update**

The other issue is that you are setting the allowed effects in your drag operation to `DragDropEffects.Copy`, but in the `DragOver` and `Drop` handlers, you're trying to do a `DragDropEffects.Move`. This won't work, as those are *not* the same operation. These must match. If you want to enable both operations on drag, you can specify both with a bitwise or:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(source, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
```

**Update 2**

If you want to drop anything other than a `string` onto a `TextBox`, you have to use the `PreviewDrop` and `PreviewDragOver` events. Otherwise, the `TextBox`'s default handling will ignore anything else. So it would look like this:

```
tbox.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDrop); 
tbox.PreviewDragOver += new DragEventHandler(tbox_DragOver);
```

Comment: hi , i have set IsHitTestVisible = false . it still won't drop . Sorry but i don't quite understand your second sentence on drop attempt and stuffs

Comment: Basically, WPF will do a hit test at the cursor location and try to drop on the top most element. If that element doesn't accept drops, the operation will be cancelled. That is why disabling hit testing on your `Adorner` is important (`Adorner`s are always on top).

Comment: i have disabled hittest , doesn't work , is there any other problems ?

Comment: Hi i have tried Copy and Move together , doesn't work too .. is it because an adorner can't be drag into a textbox?

Comment: No, you aren't dragging the `Adorner`. You are dragging whatever you pass to `DragData`. So, in your case, you're likely passing a `Window`. Which the `TextBox` won't accept by default. Since you said it was working before you added the `Adorner`, I didn't think you were having issues with that. I've updated the answer to explain how to work around this.

Comment: I had tried preview before that . The problem doesn't lies in the DragAdorner class file?

Comment: i solved it , TextBox won't accept dragdata , it have to be text . I'll accept yours as an answer .

Comment: Well, with `PreviewDrag` and `PreviewDrop`, you can manipulate the data so that you drop what you want on to the `TextBox`. But if you drag a string, the `TextBox` can handle it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background color for your label and see if it will work properly.